# Как для плагина multiscroll сделать блоки друг за другом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как для плагина multiscroll сделать блоки друг за другом при сужении окна браузера? вот пример: https://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/extensions/responsive-expand.html#second там блоки становятся друг за другом когда браузер меньше 1000px

Comment: Это платное расширение для multiscroll, но, если покапаться, можно рипнуть его из припера по ссылке)

Comment: @Cheg, ай-я-яй, научите тут плохому ... @ртём PeGaS, А что касается темы, проще было бы с кодом работать ... Такие штуки обычно решаются через `!important` и `width: 100%; height: 100vh;` (если сам плагин не поддерживает).